# jquery mobile parameter passing using change page

Tags: jquery, mobile

```
i have in jquery mobile when i passing parameter using change page.

$("#mytest-listview div.mytest-title a").live('click', function (event,data) {
    var cid = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(cid);

    $.mobile.changePage('../mytestdetail/',{ type: "get", data: {"id":cid} , reloadPage:false, changeHash:true });

    $('#pgMyTestDetail').live('pageshow', function(){
        var id = $.urlParam('id');
        doLoadMyTest(id);

    });

    $.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        return results[1] || 0;
    }
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

when i click on mytest title it pass the id of mytest to url and then i get the id value and show the all detail of mytest. here is url /test/testdetail/?id=26 , but when i get test detail page and i hit the ctrl+R it refresh the page but not show the test detail. whats the problem?

Comment: If you're still having trouble with this, my [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) might help

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.4, jQuery Mobile [does not support page parameters](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2859#issuecomment-22472030). For version 1.5, the [roadmap](http://jquerymobile.com/roadmap/) includes "Hash/query params according specs".

A workaround would be to use a custom router such as [Cameron Askew's paramsHandler](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler).

Other router options include [jquerymobile-router](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router), which at the time of writing is not up-to-date with jQuery Mobile 1.4, or [Backbone's router](http://mrbool.com/backbone-js-router/28001), which could require extensive integration to support jQuery Mobile's features.

Alternatively, `click` and `vclick` events can be intercepted and directly handled to add parameter support, e.g. saving the parameters in a variable before the page transition.

Comment: I think those router's may be out of date. I recently created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) for jQM 1.4

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#mytest-listview div.mytest-title a").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cid = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(cid);
            $.mobile.changePage('../mytestdetail/', { type: "get", data: {"id": cid}, reloadPage: false, changeHash: true });


        });
    //});

    $(document).on("pageinit", "#pgTestDetail", function (e) {
        var cid = (($(this).data("url").indexOf("?") > 0) ? $(this).data("url") : window.location.href ).replace(/.*id=/, "");
        doLoadTest(cid);


I write above code and its works great even refresh the page using ctrl+r.
```